# Find product of shifted plot and other plot in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

In the MWE, I shifted the blue plot to the left.  How can I now plot the product of the shifted plot (in cyan), and the blue plot?

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
%\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{filecontents*}{MAG.dat}
  Iter   Abs1   Abs2      x      y
     1, 0.9317521, 1.1849326, 1.6130556, 0.8022207
     2, 1.8946202, 1.1228282, 1.8964566, -0.5353802
     3, 1.5243302, 1.0372991, 1.4375012, 0.9719003
     4, 1.5797030, 1.1346832, 1.8717142, 0.3138737
     5, 1.8814457, 1.0529187, 2.0568468, -0.5509391
     6, 2.0435003, 1.0470546, 2.0621956, -0.3565483
     7, 2.0373926, 1.1215579, 2.1836100, 0.3360301
     8, 1.9797077, 1.1632352, 1.8299063, 0.3871091
     9, 1.9972528, 1.1952478, 1.8133509, -0.0867033
    10, 1.8320176, 1.0625633, 1.0727495, 1.7256738
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dotted,gray!90}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style={gray!70!black},
            every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
            every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.8pt},
            }

\newcommand{\bod}{MAG.dat}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[width=14cm,height=10.2cm,
                    grid = both,
                    log ticks with fixed point,
                    every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.9},
                    title = {},
                    xlabel={\emph{\bfseries{Iteration}}},
                    ylabel={\emph{\bfseries{Temp}}},
                    no markers,
                    every axis plot/.append style={very thick},
                    legend style={at={(0,0)},anchor=south west},
                    legend cell align=left,
                    ]

\addplot+ [red]table[x index=0,y index=1, col sep=comma] {\bod};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta = 0.3$};
\addplot+ [blue]table[x index=0,y index=3, col sep=comma] {\bod};
\addlegendentry{$\zeta = 0.5$};
\addplot+ [cyan]table[x index=0,y index=3, x expr=(\thisrowno{0}/2), col sep=comma] {\bod};
\addlegendentry{\emph{Shifted}};

\addlegendentry{\emph{Sum}}

\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by product. Would another plot with `x expr=(\thisrowno{0}/2*\thisrowno{0})` do the trick? If you mean sum as the last `\addlegendentry` implies wouldn't `x expr=(\thisrowno{0}/2+\thisrowno{0})` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the blue and cyan plots mean, that the x and y values are taken from different data rows. However, `pgfplots` processes them row by row. Therefore, it is IMHO much easier, to parse the data and calculate the wanted function in the programming language of your choice and provide the result as data file again.